# Jenkins and reporting, non-existent?

Tags: jenkins, reporting

I have been using Jenkins for a while now and coming from a .NET world using Team Foundation Server, one thing I miss the most is reporting through notifications. I know Jenkins is only a subset of TFS's functionality so the comparison is not fair.

However, if there is one thing that is important when leveraging these type of CI and QA tools then it is notifying the team about progress and quality. Jenkins can show some graphs on the dashboard, but I still haven't found a way to send my team emails containing unit test graphs, build stability graphs, pipeline graphs, etc. They simply do not exist, or have I just not found them? Sure, Jenkins can email content like failed tests, but that is too low-level. Teams need to see historical graphs about progress.

Comment: Check out [Email Extension plugin][1]. If Jenkins shows the information you need on dashboard, I am pretty sure you can put this info into email too. I personally didn't use this plugin, so I cannot help you any further here, sorry.

[1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: I am using that plugin, but it can only report failed tests. I have asked around and the response has been that graphics from the dashboard cannot be included in email. This would solve the problem though...

Answer (score 1):

The format and content of the **[Email Ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)** can be set as needed -
just set it to link to any page you like
(can add the link to the existing content of the mail, or replace it all together).

Apart from that, I don't recall support for any statistical graphs, sorry.

Comment: Yes, a link can be added to the email. However, no graph can be actually inserted into the email.